# enabling drag and drop on a touchscreen mobile device

Tags: jquery, android, browser, mobile, mobile-phones

I just recently got an android phone and found that the drag and drop on my site doesn't work! I understand why it wouldn't, but has anyone found a solution to this? I'm using JQuery to implement the D & D...

Comment: Mark the right answer.

Answer (score 33):

I used jQuery UI touch punch - it works by hacking the mousedown, mouseup features and replaces them with touchstart, touchend etc.

ABOUT:
http://touchpunch.furf.com/

SCRIPT:
https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

CODE:

include:

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

after your jquery UI script file in your header.

Comment: TouchPunch saved my ass. Works on iPad and Nexus 7. Thanks

Comment: TouchPunch works great, thanks for reminding me of this library.

Comment: Unreal. Thanks you so much. Pity you didn't get the marks for the answer

Comment: Awesome! Brilliant little utility

Comment: Not the best solution: if the element to drag takes the whole viewport, using jQuery UI Touch Punch prevents the document to be scrolled. Can be even a problem with element you want to be only draggable horizontally with a container hiding overflow, as a draggable carousel. In this case, the carousel prevents user to scroll the document up and down. I prefer jQuery Touch (github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch) which makes draggable possibly touch only on mobile (mouse gesture can be filtered) and does not prevent touch events to propagate (thus, document to be scrolled).

Answer (score 3):

I used the touchpunch answer above and it worked great. One note on it, though. I found that using the github link on the site (and above):

SCRIPT: https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

did not work for Android devices running mobile Chrome, but the raw, human readable source from the site **did** work. This is as of the date of this posting, it may get fixed of course, but in the mean time maybe it will save you a few cycles of debugging.

Comment: This pluggin (jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js) enables the drag and drop in touch mobile devices. All you have to do is just load the pluggin after jquery and jquery ui. This should work fine on all mobile devices.

Comment: Not the best solution: if the element to drag takes the whole viewport, using jQuery UI Touch Punch prevents the document to be scrolled. Can be even a problem with element you want to be only draggable horizontally with a container hiding overflow, as a draggable carousel. In this case, the carousel prevents user to scroll the document up and down. I prefer jQuery Touch (github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch) which makes draggable possibly touch only on mobile (mouse gesture can be filtered) and does not prevent touch events to propagate (thus, document to be scrolled).

Answer (score 2):

Old thread I know.......

I have here an solution that respects any input or other element that has to react on 'clicks' (for example inputs) on a draggable element. This solution made it possible to use any existing drag and drop library that is based upon mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events on any touch device (or cumputer). This is also a cross-browser solution.

I have tested in on several devices and it works fast (in combination with the drag and drop feature of ThreeDubMedia (see also http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag)). It is a jQuery solution so you can use it only with jQuery libs. I have used **jQuery 1.5.1** for it because some **newer functions don't work properly with IE9 and above** (not tested with newer versions of jQuery).

**Before** you add any **drag or drop** operation to an event **you have to call this function first**:

```
simulateTouchEvents(<object>);
```

You can also block all components/children for input or to speed up event handling by using the following syntax:

```
simulateTouchEvents(<object>, true); // ignore events on childs
```

Here is the code i wrote. I used some nice tricks to speed up evaluating things (see code).

```
function simulateTouchEvents(oo,bIgnoreChilds)
{
 if( !$(oo)[0] )
  { return false; }

 if( !window.__touchTypes )
 {
   window.__touchTypes  = {touchstart:'mousedown',touchmove:'mousemove',touchend:'mouseup'};
   window.__touchInputs = {INPUT:1,TEXTAREA:1,SELECT:1,OPTION:1,'input':1,'textarea':1,'select':1,'option':1};
 }

$(oo).bind('touchstart touchmove touchend', function(ev)
{
    var bSame = (ev.target == this);
    if( bIgnoreChilds && !bSame )
     { return; }

    var b = (!bSame && ev.target.__ajqmeclk), // Get if object is already tested or input type
        e = ev.originalEvent;
    if( b === true || !e.touches || e.touches.length > 1 || !window.__touchTypes[e.type]  )
     { return; } //allow multi-touch gestures to work

    var oEv = ( !bSame && typeof b != 'boolean')?$(ev.target).data('events'):false,
        b = (!bSame)?(ev.target.__ajqmeclk = oEv?(oEv['click'] || oEv['mousedown'] || oEv['mouseup'] || oEv['mousemove']):false ):false;

    if( b || window.__touchInputs[ev.target.tagName] )
     { return; } //allow default clicks to work (and on inputs)

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent for API
    var touch = e.changedTouches[0], newEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    newEvent.initMouseEvent(window.__touchTypes[e.type], true, true, window, 1,
            touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
            touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
            false, false, false, 0, null);

    touch.target.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
    e.preventDefault();
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
});
 return true;
};
```

What it does:
At first, it translates single touch events into mouse events. It checks if an event is caused by an element on/in the element that must be dragged around. If it is an input element like input, textarea etc, it skips the translation, or if a standard mouse event is attached to it it will also skip a translation.

Result:
Every element on a draggable element is still working.

Happy coding, greetz,
Erwin Haantjes

Comment: Thank you Erwin, seriously a great implement, work at first try, no need to tweak ! 

Tested on a ELO touch screen computer

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone at least has certain events such as ontouchstart, ontouchend, etc. These are part of webkit, but there is much less information with regards Android than iPhone. I think the answer to this question is that the drag and drop functionality needs to use those events rather than the events you would normally use, or needs to use both.

This article may be of interest - http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery drag and drop plugin that has support for mobiles / touch-screen devices:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mobiledraganddrop

On a mobile device, you tap to pick up the item and tap to select the drop location. This gets around the issue of drag actions being hijacked by the device / browser.

Comment: Aforementioned library has 4 different samples  "to drag" on their demo page.  NONE of them works on my iPad 2, be forewarned.

Comment: @alex gray, good spot. I have raised a bug against 3.0.1 for that.

Comment: Still not working on iPad2, and lots of visual artifacts / spotty functionality in desktop Webkit browsers.  http://cl.ly/0a3a0X3o3e462O3g2P2O

Comment: I can't test on iPad2 as I don't have one - it works on iPhone. The other thing is, as it's open source if you raise a bug on jquery.com someone fixes it. I think the webkit issues have now been fixed - I think the combination of mousedown and touchstart was causing multiple events to fire for the same event.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example that work on my Android tablet touchscreen
http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/drag.html
It use "ontouchstart event"