# What is the best way to support drag and drop when a browser doesn't support HTML5 drag and drop?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

My smartphone web browser supports many of HTML5's features, however it does not support HTML5 drag and drop.  Attempting to drag objects merely scrolls the browser window...which being an extremely common operation on touch devices is probably why the feature is not supported by the browser.

What is the best way to support drag and drop functionality within a webpage on a mobile device that does not support HTML5 drag-and-drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK a client cannot change the behaviour of a website. Some sites support Drag and Drop, while some don't. It all depends on the way website is designed. If you are owner of a website and would like to add D&D feature, check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034334/enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-touchscreen-mobile-device).

Also some browsers may not support this feature. Try using some other browser.

Note: It seems you are new to stackoverflow. Upvote and accept the answers if you like.